# Installing Node.js 6 parallel to existing Node.js 7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nodejs, npm

I have Node.js 7.5.0 installed. But I got some issues with my project which uses the Node.js 6.

I get this message:

```
nodejs is already the newest version (7.5.0-1nodesource1~xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
```

I tried to install the Node.js 6 with the following command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I need to install Node.js 6 on my machine. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest you remove all nodejs installed versions to work cleanly with different versions of node in your system.

**Install nodejs 6**

Get your nodejs packages from node site e.g. `node-v6.10.1-linux-x64.tar.gz` from [v6.10.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.1/)

Unpack provided archive files to `/opt/nodejs`

```
mkdir -p /opt/nodejs
tar -xvzf node-v6.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/nodejs/
mv node-v6.10.0-linux-x64 6.10.0
```

**Create link to current node version**

```
cd /opt/nodejs
ln -s 6.10.0 current
```

**Create link to current node binary**

```
ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node
```

**Verify Node version**

```
node -v
v6.10.0
```

**Install nodejs 7 in parallel**

Get the package from node site e.g `node-v7.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz` from [v7.7.4](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.7.4/)

```
tar -xvzf node-v7.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/nodejs/
mv node-v7.7.4-linux-x64 7.7.4
```

**Switch between versions**

You just need to modify the link to point to the version you want to use

```
cd /opt/nodejs
unlink current
ln -s 7.7.4 currrent
```

**Verify version is changed**

```
node -v
v7.7.4
```

Comment: Could/should this be put into ~/bin, as ~/bin is in the current $PATH, and /opt isn't? In /opt, how is the system finding nodejs if you don't modify the $PATH?

Comment: you can create a link to node binaries into /bin or ~/bin `ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to easily manage your installed Node versions. It's extremely easy to install new versions and switch between them (`nvm install v6` and `nvm use v6`), and you can set a default version with `nvm alias devault v6`.

I would recommend removing your current system Node install first, to reduce the chance of confusion in the future.